# dbus package installation is failing in ubuntu(22.04) chroot environment

Tags: 22.04, chroot

I am trying to create a customized ubuntu iso using the ubuntu(22.04) chroot virtual environment.
In chroot environment, facing issues while installing dbus package. Error logs are attached below.

root@ubuntu:/# apt-get install -y dbus

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree... Done

Reading state information... Done

dbus is already the newest version (1.12.20-2ubuntu4.1).

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 83 not upgraded.

1 not fully installed or removed.

After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.

perl: warning: Setting locale failed.

perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:

```
    LANGUAGE = (unset),

    LC_ALL = (unset),

    LC_COLLATE = "POSIX",

    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"

are supported and installed on your system.
```

perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").

E: Unlocking the slave of master fd 38 failed! - unlockpt (22: Invalid argument)

Setting up dbus (1.12.20-2ubuntu4.1) ...

Failed to generate UUID: Short read from /dev/urandom

dpkg: error processing package dbus (--configure):

installed dbus package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1

Errors were encountered while processing:

dbus

needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

root@ubuntu:/#

Comment: sudo apt install systemd-container Customize ubuntu live image: https://gist.github.com/gdamjan/62ccd8a4878112e35456

Comment: issue fixed, thanks @JohanPalych